# Не правильно работает sub menu

Tags: html, css, jquery

Пример каталог товаров на сайте https://allo.ua/ru/. Необходимо, чтобы пока курсор находится на пункте sub-link блок ".sub-block" который относится к этому sub-link не скрывался. Если курсор находится за пределами этих блоков то ".sub-block" скрывался.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-link').mousemove(function(){
      let selectionId = $(this).attr('rel');
      $('.sub-block').css('display', 'none');
      $('#' + selectionId).css('display', 'block');
    });

    $( ".sub-blocks" ).mouseout(function() {
      $( '.sub-block' ).css('display', 'none');
    });

  });
```

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
 }
 
.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sub-list {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.sub-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sub-block {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 
 .sub-title {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   margin-bottom" 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      Item 2
      <div class="sub">
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#" class="sub-link" rel="sub-1">Sub 1</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#" class="sub-link" rel="sub-2">Sub 2</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#" class="sub-link">Sub 3</a></li>
          <li class="sub-item"><a href="#" class="sub-link">Sub 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sub-blocks">
          <div id="sub-1" class="sub-block">
            <h3 class="sub-title">Title 1</h3>
            <p class="sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque odio maxime vel ea qui aperiam libero unde, quis accusamus ex, veniam rem. Aliquam enim eius maiores, fuga reprehenderit impedit et!</p>
          </div>
          <div id="sub-2" class="sub-block">
            <h3 class="sub-title">Title 2</h3>
            <p class="sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque odio maxime vel ea qui aperiam libero unde, quis accusamus ex, veniam rem. Aliquam enim eius maiores, fuga reprehenderit impedit et!</p>
            <p class="sub-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque odio maxime vel ea qui aperiam libero unde, quis accusamus ex, veniam rem. Aliquam enim eius maiores, fuga reprehenderit impedit et!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить mousemove на mouseover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-link').mouseover(function(){
      let selectionId = $(this).attr('rel');
      $('.sub-block').css('display', 'none');
      $('#' + selectionId).css('display', 'block');
    });

    $( ".sub-blocks" ).mouseout(function() {
      $( '.sub-block' ).css('display', 'none');
    });

  });
```

Comment: Спасибо! К сожалению не подходит